# If statement check list contains is returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a list which contains the values:

```
['1', '3', '4', '4']
```

I have an if statement which will check if the values are contained within the list then output a statement:

```
if "1" and "2" and "3" in columns:
    print "1, 2 and 3"
```

Considering the list doesn't contain value "2", it should not print the statement, however it is:

**Output:**

```
1, 2 and 3
```

Can someone explain why this is the case? Is it the way Python reads the list that is making this occur?

Comment: `in` precedes over `and`. when in doubt, add parenthesis.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It gets evaluated in order of [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

```
if "1" and "2" and ("3" in columns):
```

Expands into:

```
if "1" and "2" and True:
```

Which then evaluates `("1" and "2")` leaving us with:

```
if "2" and True
```

Finally:

```
if True:
```

Instead you can check if the `set` of strings are a subset of `columns`:

```
if {"1", "2", "3"}.issubset(columns):
    print "1, 2 and 3"
```

Comment: Ah i understand, yeah I didn't think about it that way. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would be better to say that **`"1" and "2" and "3"` returns `"3"`** and **`"3" in columns` returns `True`**. This is because "*neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but rather return the last evaluated argument*". [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) :)

Comment: @elegent Ah you're of course correct. I was just thinking in terms of "Truthiness", but what you're saying is what is actually happening.

Comment: @KitSunde: Yes I was surprised too :D

Comment: As it stands, this explanation is wrong, for the reasons elegent stated. Considering it's the top voted and accepted answer, please take the time to correct it, otherwise we're misinforming people. If you don't mind, I'll be happy to do it

Comment: In fact, you are evaluating `"1" and "2" and True` which returns `True`.

Comment: I am sorry! **My explanation is wrong too!!** Please see @goncalopp [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31784924/4594443)

Comment: you can also use `set(["1", "2", "3"]) <= columns`. It's a neat syntactic sugar and reads a little bit nicer

Comment: @WorldSEnder You would need to make both ends a `set`. `set(["1", "2", "3"]) <= set(columns)`. issubset on the other hand takes an iterable.

Comment: You are right. the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) say something else - also for python 2

Comment: You can use set literals: `{"1", "2", "3"}.issubset(columns)`

Comment: I'm impressed by everyone's dedication, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

There's two general rules to keep in mind in order to understand what's happening:

- **a boolean operator always [returns the result of the evaluation of one operand](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)**.
- **operations are executed in the [order of precendence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)**

When evaluating the expression `"1" and "2" and "3" in columns`, the [order of operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) makes this be evaluated as `"1" and "2" and ("3" in columns)`. This is thus expanded to `"1" and "2" and True`, since `"3"` is indeed a element of `columns` (note that single or double quotes are interchangeable for python strings).

> Operators in the same box group left to right

Since we have two operators with the same precedence, the evaluation is then `("1" and "2") and True` .

For `and`, the [documentation for boolean operations states](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#and):

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

Thus, `("1" and "2") and True` evaluates to `"2" and True`, which then evaluates to `True`.Therefore your `if` body always executes.

Comment: Yah :) there we go :D Should I delete my answer? :)

Comment: @elegent I don't think you should delete your answer - now that you've corrected the operator precedence, I think it's the quickest to understand for people who already have a good understanding of python

Comment: Thanks :) I will link to your answer! If you don't mind you could upvote my last comment for @KitSunde answer, which says that my first comment is wrong -- so everybody can see it immediately.